# How do I get my search function work to filter searched items from table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've made a table filled with data retreived from a JSON file. Now I'm trying to make a searchbar that filters searched items and only shows the table rows of the items searched for. The code of the function I'm using now is:

```
//Search function
          function searchTable() {
        var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
        input = document.getElementsByClassName("searchBar");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("productTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                found = false;
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is the HTML of the table I'm trying to apply the filter to:

```
<input class="form-control searchBar" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Free Stock</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="productTable">
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: You are missing `#` in `$('productTable tr')`

Comment: That did do something, but now every single row disappears when I type in 1 letter in the searchbar. When I remove the letter from the searchbar, the results are still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is getElementsByClassName does not return an element. Instead, it returns a NodeList. If you only have a single element with class=“searchBar” then you would reference as:

```
input = document.getElementsByClassName("searchBar")[0];
```

**Updated script with your existing ID is**

```
function searchTable() {
        var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
        input = document.getElementsByClassName("searchBar")[0];
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("productTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                found = false;
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

However, if you are only going to have one of these elements, I suggest giving it an id and use getElementById and then you will actually get an element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution for searching inside HTML table while covering all of the table, (all td, tr in the table), pure javascript and as short as possible:

```html
<body style="background:red;">
<input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchTable()' type='text'>
<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Free Stock</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>elit</td>
      <td>Mumbai</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>sud</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>button</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function searchTable() {
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Getting the following error when I'm trying your code: Uncaught ReferenceError: searchTable is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup. 

I changed the input to <input class="form-control searchBar" id='myInput' onkeyup="searchTable()" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search"> 

and I changed the script to input = document.getElementById("myInput"); and table = document.getElementById("productTable");

Comment: It is working fine here if I add your these code also. but why you are changing code. Do You want to put your ID?

Comment: I want to apply your solution to my existing table, that's why I changed the id's of your input and table to the id's I used for thesee variables. I will edit the code in my question to my most recent code, so you can check it out :)

Comment: The problem is getElementsByClassName does not return an element. Instead, it returns a NodeList. If you only have a single element with class=“searchBar” then you would reference as:'' input = document.getElementsByClassName("searchBar")[0];''

Comment: I am adding my another answer for it

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue though, since the error in my console still says that 'searchTable' is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup. And I'm using these classes for the Bootstrap styling.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Here is code running with your existing ID and class. Can you please share URL OR codpen link?

Comment: Yes sure, link to the project on my Github is: https://github.com/Yboeckholtz/Vesta/tree/develop